# Postgresql Exact match using Full text ts_query

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I want to match all exact match including:

```
- Exact match
- Plurals
- Mispelling
```

Table data:

- natural loofah (YES - Exact match)
- natural loofahs (YES - Exact match with plural)
- natural lofah (YES - Exact match with misspelling)
- Loofah natural (NO)
- all natural loofah (NO - It's not exact match)

I tried with this but its not working

```
SELECT

    query

FROM reports
WHERE to_tsvector('english', query)  @@ websearch_to_tsquery('english', 'natural loofah') 
GROUP BY query
```

Answer (score 0):

No this won't work. You have misunderstood what full text search does: it searches for whole words (optional: prefixes), ignoring flexion.

Full text search does *not* search for similarity.

Maybe you'd be better off with a trigram index:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX ON reports USING gin (query gin_trgm_ops);

SELECT query
FROM reports
WHERE query % 'natural loofah';
```

Here `%` is the similarity operator.

Comment: Ok for similarity. What about to achieve an exact match (with plurals and ignoring stop words in different languages) with full text?

Comment: You can only support one language. If you want several languages, you need to `OR` conditions for each language. But full text search would work for that.

Comment: Ok, how can achieve exact match only in English? I want to exclude all before and after my query

Comment: I am interested in the argument of ts_query to exclude everything before and after “natural loofah”

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: If i use ts_query(“natural & loofah”) is does return also “ABC natural loofah ABC”. I want to exclude all words before and after “natural loofah”

Comment: That won't work with full text search. Similarity matching like in my answer is what you need.

Comment: If I exclude the other results with an "AND" operator ? I really need the full-text because it exclude stop words too and it's very precise for my need. The only negative point is to exclude before/after.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense to me. You want to exclude stop words from the search, but there should be nothing before and after the match. What if there is a stop word before your match?

Comment: Exactly. If there is a stop word would be better to not excluded but it is not possibile it’s ok.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to trigram search, Postgres also has a text processor called 'simple' that will leave in stopwords and not perform any stemming on the search terms. This will let you do exact phrase matches on your query document, just be aware of what you lose in building a search index with 'simple'.

```
# select * from websearch_to_tsquery('english', '"eats, shoots, and leaves"');
     websearch_to_tsquery     
------------------------------
 'eat' <-> 'shoot' <2> 'leav'
(1 row)

# select * from websearch_to_tsquery('simple', '"eats, shoots, and leaves"');
            websearch_to_tsquery            
--------------------------------------------
 'eats' <-> 'shoots' <-> 'and' <-> 'leaves'
(1 row)
```